# Convert 2D Array of words into single Array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of arrays with sentences in each element. I want to end up with one single array with each word split up by spaces and then get the length of the whole array

I know I need to loop through the array and then apply split but is there a better way?

```js
const temp2 = [
  ['this is an array'],
  ['this is a scentence'],
  ['I love stackoverflow']
]
console.log(
  temp2[0][0].split(' ').length // 3 words
)
```

Comment: That code is invalid and poorly formatted. You should add a [mcve].

Comment: Why is there a single sentence in each sub-array? What's the point of that?

Comment: `const lengths = temp2.map(elem => elem[0].split(' ').length)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simpler logic

- Convert your multi dimensional array to a single dimensional array with `Array.flat` [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- Convert this array to a single string using `Array.join` [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- Spilt this single sting on spaces using regex `/\s+/` with `String.split` [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- Find the length of the generated array.

```js
const temp2 = [['this is an array'],['this is a scentence'],['i love stackoverfloe']];
const output = temp2.flat().join(' ').split(/\s+/).length;
console.log(output)
```

Comment: That is identical to the [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69174343/295783)

Comment: identical but well explained, thats why he gets the tick!

Comment: @mplungjan thx for your supporting voice of reason 

Answer (score 2):

- Use [Array.prototype.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)  to flatten the nested array into a single array or words
- Use [Array.prototype.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to convert the Array to a string joined by whitespace.
- [Split the string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) by one or more spaces

```js
const temp2 = [
  ['this is an array'],
  ['this is a scentence'],
  ['i love stackoverfloe']
]

const arr = temp2.flat().join(" ").split(/ +/);
console.log(arr);  // or use: arr.length
```

Answer (score 0):

[flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to the rescue

I use `.split(" ")`, you can use `.split(/ +/)` if there are possibly multiple spaces and `.split(/\s+/)` for all types of whitespace

```js
const temp2 = [
  ['this is an array'],
  ['this is a scentence'],
  ['I love stackoverflow']
]
console.log(
  temp2.flatMap(arr => arr[0].split(" ")).length 
)
```

If you have more than one entry per nested array, you can do

```
  temp2.flatMap(arr => arr.join(" ").split(/ +/))
```

```js
const temp2 = [
  ['this is an array', 'this is a scentence'],
  ['I love stackoverflow']
]
console.log(
  temp2.flatMap(arr => arr.join(" ").split(/ +/)).length
)
```

Last alternative is to count words `.match(/\b\w+\b/g)`

```js
const temp2 = [
  ['this is an array'],
  ['this is a scentence'],
  ['I love stackoverflow']
]
console.log(
  temp2
    .map(arr => arr[0].match(/\b\w+\b/g).length)
    .reduce((a,b)=> a+b)
)
```

Comment: "flat" answers do not account for multiple phrases per array, as in `["one two", "three four"]`. Something like `.map(a => a.join(' ')).join(' ').split` would be more robust.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` on the array and split each item in the array

```js
    const temp2 = [
       ['this is an array'],
       ['this is a scentence'],
       ['i love stackoverfloe']
    ]
    
    const words = temp2.reduce(
      (arr, sentence) => { 
        return [...arr, ...sentence[0].split(' ')]
      }, 
      []
    )
    console.log(words)
```

If you are targeting modern browser, the other answers using `.flat()` and `.flatMap()` are better. If you are targeting older browsers (such as IE) those won't work while reduce is supported.

Comment: That is really overkill

Comment: Yeah I agree, the other answers using `.flat()` and `.flatMap()` are better. I actually didn't now about those functions

Answer (score -2):

try this, maybe this is what you want:

```js
const temp2 = [
  ['this is an array'],
  ['this is a scentence'],
  ['i love stackoverfloe']
]

let res = temp2.reduce((prev, next) => {
    const tempArr = next[0].split(" ")
    for (let i = 0; len = tempArr.length, i < len; i ++) {
        prev.push(tempArr[i])
    }
    return prev
}, [])

console.log("res", res)
console.log("res.length", res.length)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use [Array#floatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [String#match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Match):

```js
const temp2 = [['this is an array'], ['this is a scentence'], ['i love stackoverfloe']]

const arr = temp2.flatMap(([s]) => s.match(/\S+/g))
console.log(arr.length)
```

Or [Array#reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [String#match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Match):

```js
const temp2 = [['this is an array'], ['this is a scentence'], ['i love stackoverfloe']]

const total = temp2.reduce((a, [c]) => a + c.match(/\S+/g).length, 0) 
console.log(total)
```

Comment: @mplungjan code refactored.. Thank you